# Load external page and use it's elements like I would use them normally?

Tags: javascript, dom, request

Can I load an external page using Javascript and convert it to a DOM structure so I can scrape it like I would to it normally?

Bad explanation, but code says more than thousand words, I think. ;)

```
foobar  = loadExternalPage('foobar.com');
foobar  = convertToDOM(foobar);
headers = foobar.getElementsByClassName('header');
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/HTML_to_DOM

Answer (score 1):

If the external page is on the same domain, then yes you can using `XMLHttpRequest`, then treating the response as HTML. Alternatively, load it into an iframe and access the resulting `contentDocument`.

For a page on another domain, however, it's a bit more complicated. You may want to look at PHP's [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/domdocument), which you can use to parse HTML from any domain, and even pass it back to JavaScript if you make an AJAX call to your PHP script.

Comment: "then treating the response as HTML" - can you tell me how I can convert it to an internal data-structure? Using `div.innerHTML = htmlFromRequest;` and then use it`?

Comment: I unfortunately don't get it to work using an iFrame, although FireBug displays all it's subelements, it doesn't seem to be available to Javascript?